# FCB and Int 21h/function 23h

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm, 16-bit

I need to get the file size using Int 21h / function 23h. I don't have any idea how FCB works, nor do I know how to use it. The description for Function 23h given in this [documentation](http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_010.36.html) is:

> Function 23h (35)        Get File Size, Using FCBs
>
> ```
> Returns the number of records in a file.
>
>   On entry:      AH         23h
>                  DS:DX      Pointer to an unopened FCB
>
>   Returns:       AL         00h      If matching file found
>                             FFh      If no matching file found
> ```

How am I suppose to use this?

Comment: Please edit question and add hardware and OS you are considering.

Comment: Asked 32 years too late, FCBs became obsolete in 1983.

Comment: First initialize an [FCB](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/fcb.html) (I'm sure there are examples for this in other parts of the documentation) with all the required information then invoke int 21h.

Answer (score 2):

that same page to which you linked has, at the bottom, a link to [FCB](http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_016.html). if you follow it, you'll see you need to initialize a block of memory for the FCB, and populate it with the drive number (03 for C:), filename in 8.3 format, and a couple of other fields. point ds:dx to that block of memory, set ah to 23h, and `int 21`. if al is 0, it was successful, and you can get the file length from ds:dx + 10h.

[image: patched dosbox showing debug session]

see the `b2 6a 00 00` at offset 0x10, that matches the size of the file specified:

```
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ ls -l /usr/src/dosdebug/DEBUG.TXT
-rw-r--r-- 1 jcomeau jcomeau 27314 Feb 15  2014 /usr/src/dosdebug/DEBUG.TXT
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ printf '%x\n' 27314
6ab2
```

I had to patch a bug in dosbox to get this to work, hence the slow update.

```
diff -up ./include/dos_inc.h.orig ./include/dos_inc.h
--- ./include/dos_inc.h.orig    2015-12-27 12:43:12.000000000 -0800
+++ ./include/dos_inc.h 2015-12-27 11:53:19.000000000 -0800
@@ -170,7 +170,7 @@ void DOS_BuildUMBChain(bool umb_active,b
 bool DOS_LinkUMBsToMemChain(Bit16u linkstate);

 /* FCB stuff */
-bool DOS_FCBOpen(Bit16u seg,Bit16u offset);
+Bit16u DOS_FCBOpen(Bit16u seg,Bit16u offset);
 bool DOS_FCBCreate(Bit16u seg,Bit16u offset);
 bool DOS_FCBClose(Bit16u seg,Bit16u offset);
 bool DOS_FCBFindFirst(Bit16u seg,Bit16u offset);
diff -up ./src/dos/dos_classes.cpp.orig ./src/dos/dos_classes.cpp
diff -up ./src/dos/dos_files.cpp.orig ./src/dos/dos_files.cpp
--- ./src/dos/dos_files.cpp.orig    2015-12-27 10:08:26.000000000 -0800
+++ ./src/dos/dos_files.cpp 2015-12-27 12:22:17.000000000 -0800
@@ -964,7 +964,7 @@ bool DOS_FCBCreate(Bit16u seg,Bit16u off
    return true;
 }

-bool DOS_FCBOpen(Bit16u seg,Bit16u offset) { 
+Bit16u DOS_FCBOpen(Bit16u seg,Bit16u offset) { 
    DOS_FCB fcb(seg,offset);
    char shortname[DOS_FCBNAME];Bit16u handle;
    fcb.GetName(shortname);
@@ -972,7 +972,7 @@ bool DOS_FCBOpen(Bit16u seg,Bit16u offse
    /* First check if the name is correct */
    Bit8u drive;
    char fullname[DOS_PATHLENGTH];
-   if (!DOS_MakeName(shortname,fullname,&drive)) return false;
+   if (!DOS_MakeName(shortname,fullname,&drive)) return (Bit16u)false;

    /* Check, if file is already opened */
    for (Bit8u i=0;i<DOS_FILES;i++) {
@@ -982,16 +982,16 @@ bool DOS_FCBOpen(Bit16u seg,Bit16u offse
            if (handle==0xFF) {
                // This shouldnt happen
                LOG(LOG_FILES,LOG_ERROR)("DOS: File %s is opened but has no psp entry.",shortname);
-               return false;
+               return (Bit16u)false;
            }
            fcb.FileOpen((Bit8u)handle);
-           return true;
+           return handle;
        }
    }

    if (!DOS_OpenFile(shortname,OPEN_READWRITE,&handle)) return false;
    fcb.FileOpen((Bit8u)handle);
-   return true;
+   return handle;
 }

 bool DOS_FCBClose(Bit16u seg,Bit16u offset) {
@@ -1181,11 +1181,12 @@ bool DOS_FCBGetFileSize(Bit16u seg,Bit16
    char shortname[DOS_PATHLENGTH];Bit16u entry;Bit8u handle;Bit16u rec_size;
    DOS_FCB fcb(seg,offset);
    fcb.GetName(shortname);
-   if (!DOS_OpenFile(shortname,OPEN_READ,&entry)) return false;
+   if (!(entry = DOS_FCBOpen(seg, offset))) return false;
    handle = RealHandle(entry);
    Bit32u size = 0;
    Files[handle]->Seek(&size,DOS_SEEK_END);
-   DOS_CloseFile(entry);fcb.GetSeqData(handle,rec_size);
+   fcb.GetSeqData(handle,rec_size);
+   DOS_CloseFile(entry);
    Bit32u random=(size/rec_size);
    if (size % rec_size) random++;
    fcb.SetRandom(random);
```